# NHibernate execute the same query several times

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, queryover

I have stucked in executing NHibernate query several times with changing only one parameter.

Here is my code

```
  if (channelCount > 1)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < channelCount; i++)
                    {
                        int minOrderItemFirst = Session.GetNamedQuery("GetMinOrderItem")
                            .SetInt32("year", item.Year)
                            .SetString("orderKind", item.OrderKind)
                            .SetInt32("orderNo", item.OrderNo)
                            .SetInt32("orderItem", item.OrderItem)
                            .UniqueResult<int>();

                        
                        //I have minOrderItemFirst as int and I need to use it as .SetInt32("orderItem")
                        // Session.GetNamedQuery("GetMinOrderItem")
                        //    .SetInt32("year", item.Year)
                        //    .SetString("orderKind", item.OrderKind)
                        //    .SetInt32("orderNo", item.OrderNo)
                        //    .SetInt32("orderItem", minOrderItemFirst)
                        //    .UniqueResult<int>(); .... etc as said in for loop
                        // I am ok to increment minOrderItemFirst in every next call
    
                    }
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure - are you asking how to make nhibernate run a query several times, changing one parameter each time, or are you complaining that nhibernate runs a query several times when you don't want it to?

Comment: I am asking how to make it well!

Comment: Oh.. er... Well you use nHibernate in a way I don't really recognize; looks like you kinda use it like some thin wrapper around a parameterized SQL that auto maps POCOs for you, kinda like Dapper would, so really you need to probably be looking at changing GetMinOrderItem so it's based on a query like "SELECT * FROM whatever WHERE id IN (@p1,@p2,@p3)" and then calling it with 3 items at a time (for example) or looking at whether nHibernate can support table valued parameters so you can pass an entire table of values to the DB and join it.Better to send 10 values in 1 query than run 1 query 10x

Answer (score 0):

I got something like that, but I am not sure it is an ideal solution. Someone can explain how to achieve it with less code or more elegant?

```
 if (chCount > 1)
                {
                    int[] results = new int[chCount + 1];

                    int firstNumber = Session.GetNamedQuery("GetMinOrderItem")
                        .SetInt32("year", item.Year)
                        .SetString("orderKind", item.OrderKind)
                        .SetInt32("orderNo", item.OrderNo)
                        .SetInt32("orderItem", item.OrderItem)
                        .UniqueResult<int>();

                    results[0] = firstNumber;

                    for (int i = 1; i < chCount; i++)
                    {

                        results[i] = Session.GetNamedQuery("GetMinOrderItem")
                            .SetInt32("year", item.Year)
                            .SetString("orderKind", item.OrderKind)
                            .SetInt32("orderNo", item.OrderNo)
                            .SetInt32("orderItem", results[i - 1])
                            .UniqueResult<int>();
                    }
                }
```